# Can you group by multiple rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have a database tracking my videogame collection. My goal is to retrieve rows and convert them to JavaScript objects in this form:

```
{
    title: "Dark Souls",
    releaseYear: 2011,
    genres: ["RPG", "Action"],
    platforms: ["Windows", "Xbox 360", "PlayStation 3"],
    completed: false
}
```

I want to store this data in a SQLite database. My instinct is to organise it like this.

#### Table: games

```
title : String
releaseYear : Int
completed : Int (0/1 in lieu of boolean type)
```

#### Table: platforms

```
name : String
```

#### Table: genres

```
name : String
```

#### Table: games_genres_link

```
genres_id : Int
games_id: Int
```

#### Table: games_platforms_link

```
games_id : Int
platforms_id : Int
```

And I issue a query like

```
SELECT games.title,
       games.releaseYear,
       games.completed,
       platforms.name as platforms,
       genres.name as genres
FROM games
JOIN games_platforms_link on games_platforms_link.games_id = games.rowid
JOIN platforms on games_platforms_link.platforms_id = platforms.rowid
JOIN games_genres_link on games_genres_link.games_id = games.rowid
JOIN genres on games_genres_link.genres_id = genres.rowid
GROUP BY platforms
```

Hoping to get at least "Windows, Xbox 360, PlayStation" as the platforms field, which I can split later on, just as a starting point. But I still get two separate rows.

I'm reading up in my books and online about this, but I guess I don't quite know the terminology to even search for, because I'm struggling a little. I would really appreciate any tips anyone could offer, even something like letting me know what terms I could search to find relevant material.

Comment: you could get a list of plattforms as a subquery in the select rows part

Comment: *"My instinct is to organise it like this"* <- your instinct is right on the money :)

Comment: What is the actual output you get running your query?

Comment: Shouldn't the question be 'Can you group by multiple COLUMNS in sql'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below query, if you wanted to **group** the platforms and genres based on title,year and completed

```
SELECT games.title,
       games.releaseYear,
       games.completed,
       GROUP_CONCAT(platforms.name) as platforms,
       GROUP_CONCAT(genres.name) as genres
FROM games
JOIN games_platforms_link on games_platforms_link.games_id = games.rowid
JOIN platforms on games_platforms_link.platforms_id = platforms.rowid
JOIN games_genres_link on games_genres_link.games_id = games.rowid
JOIN genres on games_genres_link.genres_id = genres.rowid
GROUP BY games.title,games.releaseYear,games.completed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [**GROUP_CONCAT()**](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) function to get `platforms` as comma separated list.

```
SELECT games.title,
       games.releaseYear,
       games.completed,
       GROUP_CONCAT(platforms.name) as platforms,
        GROUP_CONCAT(genres.name) as genres
FROM games
JOIN games_platforms_link on games_platforms_link.games_id = games.rowid
JOIN platforms on games_platforms_link.platforms_id = platforms.rowid
JOIN games_genres_link on games_genres_link.games_id = games.rowid
JOIN genres on games_genres_link.genres_id = genres.rowid
GROUP BY games.title, games.releaseYear, games.completed,
```

Please note `GROUP_CONCAT()` uses comma as default delimiter so no need to supply another argument as comma to it.